# Does initializing your repo with README mean you can't push from local repo?

Tags: git, github

I have just created a new repo on Github with README.md as the initial commit.

Now, I want to push my project to Github so I do:

````
git push -u origin master

But I get the error: ```error: failed to push some refs to ...
updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind its remote counterpart
````

So, I assume this is because the remote repo has the README.md file and my local repo doesn't?

I try `git pull origin master`, but then I get another error: `fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories`?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the exact reason for the `updates were rejected ...` error is because there is a commit on the remote repo, and your local history does not contain this commit.

To fix this situation, things are a bit more involved than they should, because in that case the two commits do not have common history (they both are "the first commit"), so `merge` or `rebase` actions need extra options to work.

---

1. If your `README.md` is currently empty (or contains basic information, which is easy to retype), the simplest way to "fix" your situation is to overwrite this commit :

```
git push --force -u origin master
```

2. One clean way to combine the two commits is to use `git rebase --root` :

```
git fetch

# replay your local commit on top of origin/master :
# the --root option allows you to include a root commit (commit with no parent)
# in the list of rebased commits
git rebase --root origin/master master

# you can now push without '--force'
git push -u origin master
```

3. Finally, it is possible to explicitly merge two unrelated histories using the `--allow-unrelated-histories` option on `git merge` or `git pull` :

```
git fetch origin
git merge --allow-unrelated-histories origin/master

# equivalent to:
git pull --allow-unrelated-histories origin master
```

Using the third option, the beginning of your history will look a bit unusual :

```
$ git log --oneline --graph
* cc1234 (HEAD, master) Merge 'origin/master' into master
|\
| * bb1234 (origin/master) add README.md
* aa1234 first commit on master
```

You will have a merge commit, which combines two root commits (commits with no parent).
But all will behave normally afterwards.

Comment: Ok, thanks! But if I now create a read me won’t I face the same problem again when I git pull? Because I’ve committed on the remote and not the local?

Comment: It won't be a problem anymore because now the histories have a common base, so the regular actions (`git pull` or `git pull --rebase`) work.